# Generate random characters VBA on many cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have create this script in VBA

```
Sub code_piece_motoculture()

    Randomize

    caractere = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lettre_nombre = ""

    For i = 1 To 15
        nombre_alea = Int(Len(caractere) * Rnd) + 1
        lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & Mid(caractere, nombre_alea, 1)
        If i = 5 Then lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & "-"
        If i = 10 Then lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & "-"
    Next

    Range("A1") = lettre_nombre

End Sub
```

And i have this result only in A1

```
ATBBM-YSHSS-G5ZVH
```

But i want different result on cells A2->A3->A4->A5 ect
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure there is cleaner, but this will achieve what you are looking for

```
Sub code_piece_motoculture()

    Randomize

    caractere = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lettre_nombre = ""

    For j = 1 To 10 'entrer le nombre de lignes desiree
    For i = 1 To 15
        nombre_alea = Int(Len(caractere) * Rnd) + 1
        lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & Mid(caractere, nombre_alea, 1)
        If i = 5 Then lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & "-"
        If i = 10 Then lettre_nombre = lettre_nombre & "-"

    Next
    Range("A" & j) = lettre_nombre
    lettre_nombre = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply ! Work 100% !

Answer (score 0):

Try this function ...

```
Public Function GenerateRandomStuff() As String
    Dim i As Long, lngNumber As Long, lngBetween As Long

    For i = 1 To 15
        lngBetween = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 2)

        If lngBetween = 1 Then
            lngNumber = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(48, 57)
        Else
            lngNumber = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(65, 90)
        End If

        GenerateRandomStuff = GenerateRandomStuff & Chr(lngNumber)

        If i = 5 Then GenerateRandomStuff = GenerateRandomStuff & "-"
        If i = 10 Then GenerateRandomStuff = GenerateRandomStuff & "-"
    Next
End Function
```

... worked nicely for me.

You can add that to a cell and there's no need to extend your macro if you want to add it to more cells, you just copy and paste the formula ...

```
=GenerateRandomStuff()
```

... if you want to stop it from refreshing each time, copy and paste special values and you're done.